# React async await not working with function component

Tags: reactjs, async-await

Service class method:

```
logInUser = (model) => {

        fetch(this.urlService.authUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: model,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        }).then((res) => { return res.json() })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
    }
```

I am trying to above method from a reach component like below,

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        login(e);
    };
```

login function in component look like,

```
const login = async (e) => {
        const data = await auth.logInUser(JSON.stringify({
            user_name: e.target.elements.user_name?.value,
            password: e.target.elements.password?.value,
        }));
        if (data?.status) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("logged_in_user_X_token", data?.data?.token);
            history.push("/dashboard");
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            setModalHeader(data?.message ?? "authentication_failed");
            setModalBody(data?.data ?? "invalid_credentials");
            setShowModal(true);
        }
    }
```

but here `data` always showing null and going to else part but when i am debugging the code i can see it's returning data from
`logInUser` method.

Comment: what do you get if you console.log `data` inside your async login function? Before checking the status of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to `return` the Promise in `logInUser`. That's why the output of `await auth.logInUser(..)` is `undefined`.

```
logInUser = model => {
    return fetch(this.urlService.authUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        body: model,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
};
```

Comment: @A_Sk, check this out !!